# Lubuntu 14.04 : Unable to enter GUI/system after giving login and password in login GUI

Tags: boot, lubuntu

Background: I am Windows user. I recently started using Lubuntu 14.04 along with Windows on my machine.

Problem: I am unable to go to main GUI after login (before that I was able to login and use Lubuntu GUI with same login and password). The system just freezes (but mouse pointer moves) and only wallpaper is shown. I have to forcefully(hard) shutdown the system. When I shutdown the system, then Lubuntu shutdown screen appears.

What I did with system: Grub (2.02 Beta 2) >

```
Advanced options for Ubuntu Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0.37-generic Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0.37-generic (recovery mode) > dpkg Repair broken packages root Drop to root shell prompt (I am able to go to root shell)

        Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0.36-generic
        Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0.36-generic  (recovery mode)
```

My perception: I think Lubuntu GUI is get corrupted.

Can some one guide me how can solve problem of Lubuntu GUI with out losing data in different folders of Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

As a new linux user, I'd try reinstalling Lubuntu-desktop packages first.

Let the machine boot into Lubuntu.  When you get to the point you see the desktop background and can move the mouse, press CTRL ALT F2.  This should bring you to terminal #2.  (Graphics environment is on Terminal 7 (F7))

Login using your regular details and you should get a regular terminal prompt.

Type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Enter your password, when it finishes, type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop
```

and allow the system to complete the reinstall.

then type:

```
sudo reboot
```

If this does not solve the issue, we can go from there.